# After installing Clear Linux on VMware Player 15, it launches the installer again

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm trying to download clear linux on my VMware player 15. I got windows 10. But each time I press "install", it installs the files of the OS, and then I press "Reboot" when it's finished, but it keeps returning to the default window: [image]

I think that the problem may reside in the fact that I got 2 options drivers to configure in: [image]

I followed this manual: https://clearlinux.org/documentation/clear-linux/get-started/virtual-machine-install/vmw-player

Comment: You are forgetting to umount the installation DVD.

Comment: Hey, Now I did it, but I didn't manage to "Clear Linux OS needs UEFI support to boot. To enable UEFI, add the following line to the end of your VM’s .vmx file:"
So it still doesn't work, how do I do it?

Comment: There's a vmname.vmx file in the directory you chose when you created the VM with VMware. Something like `C:\Users\DorSuki\Documents\Virtual Machines\Clear Linux VM\Clear Linux VM.vmx`. Edit it with notepad.